# Static files on s3 of django project not being rendered in nginx server

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3, gunicorn

I have stored the static files and media files in the S3 bucket and django project is stored in ec2 instance. I am using the nginx and gunicorn for server. The static files are being served in my local server but not in the nginx server.
[on local server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9TzT.png)

but on the nginx server it gives 403 error
[server error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnSNj.png)

You can check for your self http://54.226.78.2/

This is my github repo link in case you want to see the project code
https://github.com/HamzaArif538/BlueWays

Below is my sites-available/myproject file's code

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 54.226.78.2;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/project/BlueWays/static/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

and this is the journalctl gunicorn log
[journalctl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLgYO.png)

and below is my gunicorn.service file code

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/project/BlueWays
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/project/env/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          blueways.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And Yes my S3 bucket is public and i also added CORS and Bucket Policy

Comment: With 403 it seems to be a permission error, what is the output of this command: `sudo namei -om /home/ubuntu/` on the nginx server?